# Installing software for other users in Windows

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

New to Windows, so please help me out with the following:

1. From an admin user account can I install software for only specific standard user accounts and not all? If so, how?
2. If I install software from an admin user account and it shows up for all standard users, then create a new standard user account in the future, will it have access to the software too? That is, will Windows automatically add Start Menu shortcuts to the software and so on in future when I create new accounts?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20668036,  [Windows installation context](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installation-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From an Admin user account, you cannot install software for another user without doing some manual work, i.e. moving files yourself to the user's folder and changing their permissions.
2. Yes. If you install a piece of software for everyone, it goes into a special user account called "Default", which gets copied when a new user is created.

Comment: Point 2 makes sense. About Point 1 though, it seems as an admin I can install software for all users. My question was, can I restrict the installation only to certain users?

Comment: Do you know why someone gave negative points to my question and your answer?

Comment: No...  I have no idea.  This seems like a valid question and a valid response.  As for Point 1, you cannot restrict an installation to a particular user.  What you CAN do is, as an Admin, move the appropriate folders that the installer creates to their folder under "Users".  For instance, install the software to your own account, then move the folders that it creates inside your User folder to the people you want it installed for.

Comment: Would simply moving folders work though? Won't I have to change their permissions too?

Comment: Yes, you would have to change the permissions...  Sorry.